# Add hidden attributes to store other attributes values

Tags: javascript, magento

When I edit a product, I need to store the initial value of a field into another field which is hidden. I need to do this in order to compare the old value with the updated one (like a validation).

I created a new attribute and I set 'is_visible' to 0, but my question is how can I set this attribute to get the same value as another attribute.

Example:

- attribute "name" for a product has the value "Product1"
- my new hidden attribute "name_hidden" should have the same value
- I edit the "name" field to "New Product"
- when I click on save button I want to check that the value of "name" field is not equal to "name_hidden"

Comment: How are you going to get html attributes with php?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question, but if you reffer to the value I can take it using javascript

Comment: I mean that you have tagged `php` `magneto` when this is supposedly a `javascript` question. `:P`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not answer you question but it may be a solution to your problem.
When saving a product you still have access to the old data. For example you can access the old name like this:

```
$oldName = $product->getOrigData('name');
```

You don't need any new hidden attributes to be able to compare old values with new ones.
Also you can observe one of the events `catalog_product_validate_before` or `catalog_product_validate_after` where you can add your logic to validate the new values. and send the error back by throwing an exception. This will not refresh the product page and will display the error below the field. Something like this:

```
public function validateProduct($observer){
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    if ($product->getName() == $product->getOrigData('name')){ //if the name hasn't changed...feel free to change this to a condition that fits your needs.
        $up = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Exception();
        $up->setMessage('name should be changed');
        $up->setAttributeCode('name');
        throw $up; //get it? :D.
    }
}
```

This will display the error message `name should be changed` below the name input and the product won't be saved.

Comment: Once again, thank you Marius! I managed to solve my problem using a simple script. I like your solution though, and the little joke hehe :D